# Unable to import Tensorflow on Spark

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, tensorflow, bigdata

I am not able to import the Tensorflow in the Pysark2. I am getting following error

```
Python 3.4.8 (default, Apr  9 2018, 11:43:18) 
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-18)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
Setting default log level to "WARN".
To adjust logging level use sc.setLogLevel(newLevel). For SparkR, use setLogLevel(newLevel).
Welcome to
      ____              __
     / __/__  ___ _____/ /__
    _\ \/ _ \/ _ `/ __/  '_/
   /__ / .__/\_,_/_/ /_/\_\   version 2.3.0.cloudera4
      /_/

Using Python version 3.4.8 (default, Apr  9 2018 11:43:18)
SparkSession available as 'spark'.
>>> impo
>>> import tensorflow as tf
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.4/imp.py", line 243, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
ImportError: /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.17' not found (required by /usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow_internal.so)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow  # pylint: disable=unused-import
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tensorflow/python/__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 74, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.4/imp.py", line 243, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
ImportError: /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.17' not found (required by /usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow_internal.so)


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/errors

for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
above this error message when asking for help.
```

Environment details:

1. I am running Cloudera's quickstart docker image on Linux 18.04
2. I have upgraded pyspark to pyspark2 in docker image. Currnet Spark version is 2.3.0
3. Installed python3 on docker image.
4. Installed tthe Tensorflow using `sudo pip3 install tensorflow`.
5. Running pyspark2 using `pyspark2` command.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://askubuntu.com/questions/575505/glibcxx-3-4-20-not-found-how-to-fix-this-error

Comment: @DuyNguyenHoang I am running TF on docker instance. If TF in my docker image (centos) is going to refer c libs of underlying (ubuntu 18.04) then your suggested question may work.